# Hive on local Spark - how to set up?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hive

I have Spark installed locally on Windowsx64 for testing my Spark code before rolling out. I'd like to use window functions, but that requires for me to use a HiveContext. I've set the dependencies up in Maven, but when I run it on Spark, I get `The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------`
I don't have Hive set up. How can I use Spark with a HiveContext locally? I couldn't find an understandable guide on how to do that, please help!

[EDIT]
Code:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id")).orderBy(df.col("date").desc()).rowsBetween(0, 10);
Column col = avg(df.col("price")).over(window).as("price");
df = df.withColumn("price", price);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need Hive to use `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

Comment: Well, apparently I need HiveContext to do so. It's sure not working right now, Spark's looking for the Hive folder.

Comment: You should post the code.

Comment: @Dikei edited code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a [Hortonworks VM](http://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/), since apparently Hive is not well supported under Windows.